# Does Bootstrap row element have to be a direct child of column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can I have in Bootstrap a column that contains some arbitrary `<div>` element containing another arbitrary `<div>` element which contains the row - or row must be direct child of column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a `must be` in Bootstrap about this matter.

But it it good to use column as a child of row

and you can have row any where event inside a column and that will be just like nested table row.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't require that you do it any one particular way, though in my experience adding un-styled divs within one styled by bootstrap can have unpredictable effects on the alignment that are frustrating to troubleshoot.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about nesting rows in columns, then yes you can nest rows in columns and rows within those columns as well as have arbitrary content within a element that doesn't have the row or column class attached.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
       <div>content</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">content</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Refer to the [Bootstrap documentation on Nesting Grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)